# my videowriter in opencv is not saving any output

Tags: python, opencv

Using openCV in python to tag an object in a video and write that new output and save as .avi file.  Everything is working fine except for the vide writer.  I can  not get it to write and/or save the output.  It looks the same as I've done before so this is driving me insane.  Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as  np
import cv2
def draw_pyramid(pyramid, H):
    pyramid_new = []
    i=0
    for p in pyramid:
        if i !=4:
            temp_p = p
            temp_p = np.append(temp_p, 1)
            M_ext = H[0:3, :]
            p = M_ext @ temp_p
            pyramid_new.append((p[0], p[1], p[2]))
            i += 1
        else:
            pyramid_new.append((p[0], p[1], p[2]))
            i +=1
    return pyramid_new
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('hw4.avi')
got_image, img = cap.read()
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter("switch.avi",
                             fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),
                             fps=30.0,
                             frameSize=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
fx, fy, cx, cy = 675.0, 675.0, 320.0, 240.0
k = np.array([[fx,0.0,cx],[0.0,fy,cy],[0.0,0.0,1.0]])
while True:
    got_img, img = cap.read()
    if not got_img:
        break
    else:
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(src=img,
                                  code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert BGR to grayscale
        output_thresh, binary_image = cv2.threshold(src=gray_image,
                                                    maxval=255,
                                                    type=cv2.THRESH_OTSU,  # determine threshold automatically from image
                                                    thresh=0)  # ignore this if using THRESH_OTSU
        arucoDict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_100)
        corners, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image=img,
                                                  dictionary=arucoDict)
        if ids is not None and corners:
            cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(image=img,
                                          corners=corners,
                                          ids=ids,
                                          borderColor=(0, 255, 0))
            rvecs, tvecs, _ = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners=corners,
                                                                  markerLength=2.0,
                                                                  cameraMatrix=k,
                                                                  distCoeffs=None)
            cv2.aruco.drawAxis(image=img,
                               cameraMatrix=k,
                               distCoeffs=None,
                               rvec=rvecs,
                               tvec=tvecs,
                               length=2.0)
            if ids[0][0]==1:
                pyr = np.array(((-3.5/3,-1.5/3,-1.5/3,-3.5/3,-2.5),
                        (-1, -1, -1/3, -1/3, -2),
                        (-4/3, -4/3, -4/3, -4/3, -5))).T
                R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)[0]
                r = R[0]
                # rvec_m_c = rvecs[0]  # This is a 1x3 rotation vector
                tm_c = np.array(tvecs[0]).T  # This is a 1x3 translation vector
                t = np.array([[-2.5, -2, -5]]).T
                H = np.block([[R, t], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
            if ids[0][0] == 0:
                pyr = np.array(((1.5/3, 3.5/3, 3.5/3, 1.5/3, 2.5),
                                (-1,-1,-1/3, -1/3, -2),
                                (-4/3, -4/3, -4/3, -4/3, -1))).T
                R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)[0]
                # r = R[0]
                tm_c = np.array(tvecs[0]).T  # This is a 1x3 translation vector
                t = np.array([[2.5, -2, -1]]).T
                H = np.block([[R, t], [0,0,0,1]])
            pyramid_new = draw_pyramid(pyr, H)
            pyramid_new = np.asarray(pyramid_new)
            pyramid_new = pyramid_new.reshape(-1, 3)
            dist_coeff = np.zeros((4,1))
            pyramid_points, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(pyramid_new,
                                                         rvecs,
                                                         tvecs,
                                                         np.array(k),
                                                         distCoeffs=dist_coeff)
            pyramid_points = pyramid_points.astype(int)
            froml = [1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3]
            fromr = [4,4,4,4,1,2,3,0]
            color = (0,0,255)
            for i, j in zip(froml, fromr):
                cv2.line(img, tuple(pyramid_points[i][0]),
                         tuple(pyramid_points[j][0]), color, 1)
        videoWriter.write(img)
        cv2.imshow('switch', img)
        cv2.waitKey(30)
videoWriter.release()
```

Comment: How is it not working? What are the results? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: No error message.  There's just no .avi file being produced.  The images I draw into the video show and it plays in the loop but once its exits the program normally there is no final .avi video of what I just watched.

Comment: is a very small file generated? Make sure your application has access to the opencv_fmmpeg dll (if you use windows) and that the relative pathes are what you expect them to be.